# About Taylor series of function

Tags: real-analysis

Let us consider the function defined by

[![function defined by ][1]][1]

We have f(0)=0
How we show that f(x) is not equal to it's Taylor expansion at x=O

I try to get coefficients, 
$c_0 = 0$,
$c_1= $[image]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDeRD.jpg unable to find this limit, please tell me how i prove this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show that $$f^{(n)}(0)=0$$

which means that the Taylor expansion of $f$ at $x=0$ is

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty f^{(n)}\frac{x^n}{n!} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty 0 = 0$$

and $0$ (the Taylor expansion of $f$) is clearly not equal to $f$.

Comment: I am unable to find first derivative ie above limit

Comment: @samankumar Do you remember that if $p$ is a polynomial and $a>1$, then $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{p(x)}{a^x} = 0$$